# Getting SOAPFaultException in Websphere 8.5.5.0

Tags: web-services, websphere-7, websphere-8, webservices-client

When I am trying to call a web-service on `Websphere 8.5.5.0` I am getting below exception.The same is working in `Weblogic`.

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Internal Error
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1353)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1079)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.java:680)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:626)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:566)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:432)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.generateDocument(Unknown Source)
```

*Can some one point out is this the problem with websphere version or any other ?*

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying Axis with your application? If so, you probably have a conflict between that and WebSphere 8.5's built-in JAX-WS support, which is based on Axis. If that is the case, try not deploying the Axis jars.